# How to send emails using Jinja2 as a Scrapy extension

Tags: web-scraping, jinja2, scrapy, premailer

Do you know or have an example of how to create and send emails with [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) and [Premailer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/premailer) as a Scrapy extension?

If I shouldn't use them with Scrapy, what other HTML templating solution do you recommend to send advanced emails?

Comment: could you explain a bit more why should they be working with scrapy?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can send emails with `Scrapy` and `jinja2`. We do it all the time to be alerted from our scrapers. We use [mandrill](http://www.mailgun.com/) to send out our emails but you can use any other SMTP providers out there to send out your emails. Also you can extend this code to implement `premailer` into the template.

```
import requests
from scrapy import signals
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader

class EmailExt(object):
    """
    Email extension for scrapy
    """

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        """
        On `spider_closed` signal call `self.spider_closed()`
        """
        ext = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_closed,
                                signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return ext

    def spider_closed(self, spider, reason):

        #initialize `PackageLoader` with the directory to look for HTML templates
        env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('templates', 'emails'))

        template = env.get_template("email-template.html")

        # render template with the custom variables in your jinja2 template
        html = template.render(title="Email from scraper", count=10)

        # send the email using the mandrill API
        requests.post('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/yourcompany/messages',
                      auth=('api', 'API-KEY-FOR-MANDRILL'),
                      data={'from': 'support@gmail.com',
                            'to': 'myemail@gmail.com',
                            'subject': 'Email from scraper',
                            'html': html})
```